# Account Extended Private Key / BIP32 Extended Private Key need to import MetaMask?

Tags: metamask, private-key, import, bip39, export

I would withdraw ETH from my Binance account and give ETH as christmas gift to my nephew and my niece.

1: Is it any drawback in a long run if I use not the ETH network but BSC? In 10-20 years or so. Transaction fee is much cheaper in BSC.

2: I would create a paper wallet with BIP39: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

I give them the 12 word. I guess it is important to choose the ETH as coin. When I withdraw money I guess I need to use the first address in the table, right?

[image]

What about when they want to reach the money, i.e. with MetaMask. They need the private key, which one? Account Extended Private Key or BIP32 Extended Private Key?

Is it any other important aspect I should take care of?

Answer (score 0):

With the seed phrase and the derivation path `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0` is enough to calculate the private key associated with the address.

Currently for metamask private keys are 64 hex characters. Other wallet may accept other formats like bip32 extended private keys.